Не получается сделать так чтобы при вводе "с днем рождения" и нажатия кнопки "Проверить" выводился отдельный сценарий
Хочу сделать игру с сюрпризом для брата, но не получается запустить другой код после нажатия кнопки "Проверить"
Вот код:
# Импорты
from tkinter import *
from random import choice, sample


# команды
    # Начало     
def start():
    global word, wm, eg
    By.place_forget()
    Bn.place_forget()
    SB['text'] = 'Проверить'
    SB['command'] = check
    SB.place(relx=0.5, y=300, anchor=CENTER)
    word = choice(words)
    wm = sample(word, k=len(word))
    LW['text'] = 'Загаданое слово: ' + ''.join(wm)
    eg = Entry(win, font='Arial 15 bold', width=62)
    eg.place(x=193, y=148.5)


    # Проверка ответа
def check():
    gus = eg.get()
    if gus == word:
        eg.place_forget()
        SB.place_forget()
        LW['text'] = 'Вы угадали!\n Хотите ещё?'
        By.place(x=150, y=260)
        Bn.place(x=590, y=260)
    else:
        LW['text'] = 'Вы не угадали :(, попробуйте ёще раз\nЗагадоное слово: ' + ''.join(wm)

    # закрытие программы
def close():
    if close:
        win.destroy()


    # не нужно
# def cf():
#     start()
#     DR()


    # тут проблема
def DR():
    global ge, wordDr
    wordDr = 'с днем рождения', word
    if wordDr:
        eg.place_forget()
        SB.place_forget()
        win['bg'] = 'grey'
        LW['text'] = 'У тебя сегодня день рождение?'
        ge = Entry(win, font='Arial 15 bold', width=62)
        ge.place(relx=0.5, y=180)


# Слова 
words = [
    'кошка',
    'день',
    'код',
    'дом',
    'дрон',
    'тампон',
    'с днем рождения',
]

# текст
LW = Label(win, text='', font='Arial 25 bold', fg='white', bg='black')
LW.place(relx=0.5, y=71.5, anchor=CENTER)
# кнопка
SB = Button(win, text='Начать', font='Arial 20 bold', fg='black', bg='white', width=40, height=3, command=start)
SB.place(relx=0.5, y=173, anchor=CENTER)
# да\нет
By = Button(win, text='Да', font='Arial 20 bold', fg='black', bg='green', width=20, height=6, command=start )
Bn = Button(win, text='Нет', font='Arial 20 bold', fg='black', bg='red', width=20, height=6, command=close)


mainloop()

я пытался создавать отдельные лейблы, но не чего не получается. Помогите пожалуйста
Изменено:
Я хочу получить, когда ты напишешь в строку "с днем рождения" вышел не конец кода, а совсем другой сценарий где будет пару вопросов

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Я не очень понимаю что вы хотите по выходу получить. Добавьте больше подробностей, приведите примеров входных данных.

Вобщем я хочу получить по выходу отдельный сценарий типо после того как в строчке вбить "с днем рождения" и нажать проверить не переводило на конец кода, а чтобы начался совсем другой код.

@Amgarak не знаю понял ли ты, но надеюсь на помощь. Я в пост добавил изменения, прочитай их. Надеюсь ты поймёшь чего я хочу

Тебе стоит добавить в функцию check() после if gus == word: -
if word == 'с днем рождения':
    DR()


Ок. Спасибо когда проверю отвечу

Спасибо все заработало
